# Fujitsu Hard Drive asking to be formated

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure, formatting, data-loss-prevention

I have a Fujutsi hard drive that's requesting to be formatted, but if i cancel the format window it gives me this error "Data error (cyclic redundancy check)". The thing is that I don't want to format it since I'm scared to lose my important files on it.

Comment: it is not clear, can you still access the files on the disk?

Comment: No i cannot access them. I can't open the hard drive anymore..

Comment: Probably a bad drive, you should test it to be sure.  http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT